# import a bash module in C

Tags: c, bash, import

I am a beginner in programming but I am more familiar with python and bash and if I want to use bash in python I would just use `import os` and to use bash I would use `os.system("#code#")`. How do I do that in C? I am using linux mint 17.

Comment: Read [ask]. Make some research ! A good search engine will probably give you the answer. We are not a forum but a Q&A space ;)

Comment: okey. I just did not know what to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use the system() call to execute the shell script. something like this

```
int main()
{
    system("echo hello"); //system("your shell script")
}
```

so u can store your shell script in a file, open the file in c, read it line by line and execute it..

Comment: but when I enter that command and compile I get the following error: `tutorial1.c:5:9: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
  system('echo Hello!');
         ^
`

Comment: use double quotes ""  system() call passes a string as an argument

Comment: Okey, I re-wried the whole code and it compiled. Thank you